# Using ROS messages as types in another message

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a little confused about using messages as data types within another message.  Is this possible?  How does the system resolve the message type? I noticed that the Header message does not require a package name.

```
-John
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35758/using-ros-messages-as-types-in-another-message/) by [johnw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2548/johnw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `package_name/MessageName`. That external package must have a `<depends>` in your `manifest.xml`. If the included message is defined in the same package, you can leave off the `package_name/`.

`Header` is a special case.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4